# Call js at OnPageStarted sometimes not work in Reusable WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, chromium

I have implemented a reusable WebView. When I use WebView, I get WebView from pool. After using it, clear that WebView (reset settings, load `about:blank` and clear history) and return to pool.

In my code, I need to call some js at OnPageStarted.

But When I use reused WebView (which currently shows `about:blank` page) to load a url, js sometimes will be called at `about:blank`, not at my page.

I call `javascript:console.log(window.location.href)`, it shows `about:blank`. Does it mean when I call my js at OnPageStarted, DOM is not ready ? When should I call my js?

How to deal with it ?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript in WebView is not guaranteed to load until the page is finished loading.
It is best to call your JavaScript in onPageFinished.

Alternatively if you are using minimum api of 23 you can use  onPageCommitVisible().

Comment: Thanks. I deal with it by calling js on ` doUpdateVisitedHistory` callback. I had tried `onPageCommitVisible()`, it didn't work. Calling js at `onPageFinished` seems a little bit late.

Comment: doUpdateVisitedHistory is called even when you do webView.goBack(). May not be the best place.

Comment: In my case, I need to call js when every page starts to load. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of time spent trying to reproduce this error in my own app (as it does not appear consistently) I ended up adding a timer for `onPageCommitVisible` being called shortly before or after `onPageFinished`. Seems ridiculous to me but I verified that this fix works.

Here is the code in case you are interested: https://github.com/TomTasche/OpenDocument.droid/commit/c14efd6b4adfaed56150c886b4384e03209e67af

Comment: One year later, this is still happening as of today. Here's a more detailed explanation / solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302532/android-webview-onpagecommitvisible-not-fired/60478354#60478354